# Symfony Forms Neither the property "Category" nor one of the methods "getCategory()" error

Tags: sql, forms, symfony, propel

I keep getting the following error:

> Neither the property "Category" nor one of the methods
>   "getCategory()", "category()", "isCategory()", "hasCategory()",
>   "__get()" exist and have public access in class
>   "Test\TesterBundle\Model\Products"

I've got 3 tables: Products, Category and ProductCategories. The ProductCategories is the ID of the Producs and Category Table (Many to Many). But I keep getting the error above.

I've got the following form builders:

```
class ProductsType extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('ProductName');
        $builder->add('ProductDescription', 'textarea', array("required"=> false));
        $builder->add('ShortDescription', null);
        $builder->add('SKU', null);
        $builder->add('UnitWeight', null);
        $builder->add('UnitPrice', null);
        $builder->add('UnitLength', null);
        $builder->add('UnitHeight', null);
        $builder->add('UnitDepth', null);
        $builder->add('URL', null);
        $builder->add('MetaTitle', null);
        $builder->add('MetaDescription', null);
        $builder->add('MetaKeywords', null);
        $builder->add('Category', 'collection', array(
                        'type' => new \Test\TesterBundle\Form\Type\CategoryType(),
                        'allow_add' => true,
                        'allow_delete' => true,
                        'by_reference' => false, 

                    ));

    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver) {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'validation_groups' => array('newProducts'),
            'data_class' => 'Test\TesterBundle\Model\Products',
        ));
    }

    public function getName(){
        return "Products";
    } 


}
```

And The second being:

```
class CategoryType extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
                ->add('CategoryName', 'model', array(
                        'class' => 'Test\TesterBundle\Model\Productcategory',
                        'required' => false,
                        'multiple' => true,
                        'expanded' => false,
                        'property' => 'label'
                    ));
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver) {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Test\TesterBundle\Model\Productcategory'
        ));
    }

    public function getName(){
        return "ProductCategory";
    }   


}
```

Any thoughts on what would be causing the issue? I'm not sure if it's the instance that is used in the controller or if it is because I've setup the form builders incorrectly and cannot get a direct relation to the Category field (which it won't). If I use mapped => false, then it works however the builder has to populate the select box from the database, which settings mapped to false stops it doing this.

Comment: it says that you didn't add a `Category` field (or association) to `Products` entity. Add it and error disapears..

Comment: @xurshid29 Yes I know it doesn't exist in the schema in products. It needs to be independant so I can use it to map the ProductCategories for the many to many relationship (linking them together). Is that possible?

Comment: add `mappped => false` then..

Comment: @xurshid29 I have just re-arranged and I've done that, It's worked but only added the last value of the database rather then them all.

Comment: i've never tried collection type with `mapped false` option, because collection field is little bit different than regular fields..